# ¿Cómo hago para que mi menú todas las palabras se vean igual es decir con el recuadro gris por medio de css?

Tags: html, css

Esta es [mi página](https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/) ahí hay un menú que consta de **youtube**, contacto, política de privacidad, acerca de, inicio.
Quiero que **youtube** e inicio luzcan igual a contacto, política de privacidad y acerca de. no quiero que se abra una ventana modal en inicio y **youtube**, quiero que tengan el recuadro gris también, a eso me refiero.

**Este es mi código:**

```css
* *, *::before, *::after{ box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0; margin: 0;}
    body {
 background: #000000;
 color: #000000;
} 
header, footer {
 background: #000000;
 width: 90%;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin:20px auto;

}

header nav {
 background: #000000;
 overflow: hidden;
}
header nav ul {
 list-style: none;
}
header nav ul li {
 float:right;
}
 header nav ul li a {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;


 }
  header nav ul li a:hover {
   background: #55d737;
  }
 
.main {
  background: #000000;
  display: flex;
  padding: : 0px
} 


.main aside,
.main .article{
  padding: 20px;
}

.main .iz{
  width: 15%;
}
.main .de {
 width: 15%
}
.iz{
  background: #000000;
  color: #fff;
  order: 1;
}

.de{
  background: white;
  order: 3;
}

.article{
  order: 2;
  width: 70%;
  background: white;
  
}

article{
  background: white;
  margin: 5%;
}

footer {background: #000;
color:#fff;
clear:both
padding:10px 0px;
text-align: center;
}
a {margin: 20px}
.centro {
 text-align: center;
}

a.open{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 0.5em;
 margin: 20px;
 padding: 10px 20px;
 text-decoration: none;
 text-shadow: 2px 2px 0px #000;
 

}


section.modalDialog{
 background-color: white;
 bottom: 0;
 top:0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 position: fixed;
 display: none;
 z-index: 2;
}

section.modalDialog:target{
 display: block;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #414141;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 22px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 5px;
 top:5px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: 28px;
}

a.close{
 background-color: #000;
}

section.modal{
 background-color: #111;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px #000;
 border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 margin: 10% auto;
 padding: 20px;
 position: relative;
 width: 600px;
}

.diferencia {
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 2em;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.diferente{
 color: #fff;
 font-size: 1.2em;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul><li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal1" class="open"> ACERCA DE </a>
      <section id="openmodal1" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> acerca de</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Este sitio abarca tutoriales para dar soluciones destinadas a resolver dudas acerca de todo tipo de ideas útiles para el internauta</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal2" class="open">POLITICA DE PRIVACIDAD</a>
      <section id="openmodal2" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> politica de privacidad</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Esta permitido compartir todo el contenido de este sitio, más no está permitido copiar cual fiel copia, para usarlo en el desarrollo de otro sitio web, todo o parte del contenido de mi sitio web. En cualquier caso que se inserte cualquier parte del contenido en otro sitio web se deberá hacer referencia de que se está compartiendo el contenido y de forma notoria que dicho contenido es de mi autoria: Susana Alexadra Loor García y de que se extrajo de: <a href="https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com">https://alexandrawp.herokuapp.com/</a> Por lo tanto se establece que se respetará este sitio web como propiedad de la autora, y nadie se podrá adujudicar a su autoria todo del contenido de dicho sitio</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div></li>
    <li><div class="contenedor">
      <a href="#openmodal3" class="open"> CONTACTO</a>
      <section id="openmodal3" class="modalDialog">
        <section class="modal">
          <a href="#close" class="close"> X </a>
          <h2 class="diferencia"> CONTACTO</h2>
          <p class="diferente">Comunicate con nosotros a este correo susanaloorgarcia@gmail.com</p>
        </section>
      </section>
    </div> </li>
    <li><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a></li>
  </ul>
      </nav>
```

Comment: No tendrás que poner el class open tanto en inicio como en YouTube? Es que así ahora mismo no le estás aplicando el estilo CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes el youtube e inicio así :

**YOUTUBE**

```
<li>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a>

</li>
```

**INICIO**

```
<li>
   <a href="#">INICIO</a>
</li>
```

para que luzcan como deseas , ambas etiquetas `<a>` encierralas dentro de un `<div class="contenedor"></div>` , y a las etiquetas `<a>` agrégales las clases open, te guedarian los `<li>` así:

**YOUTUBE**

```
 <li>
       <div class="contenedor">
        <a target="_blank" class="open" href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCsYcSASeuWbHFBZJXy6SJEA?sub_confirmation=1">YOUTUBE</a>
       </div>
 </li>
```

**INICIO**

```
<li>
  <div class="contenedor">
     <a href="#" class="open">INICIO</a>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Si utiliza lo que @Mario Guiber dijo en el comentario, podría funcionar también. `<a class="open" href="#">INICIO</a>`

Comment: si, es parte de lo mismo que le sugiero, agregarle open a las etiquetas `a`, pero también que las encierre dentro de los `div` , para que le queden igual a los demás

Comment: Es verdad. ;-).

Answer (score 0):

Tienes q agregar la `class="open"` a los elementos q quieras q se vean con ese **style**.

Por otro lado, si los elementos de la `class open` tienen otras funcionalidades q no quieras compartir con YouTube ni Inicio, puedes crearles otra clase distinta, con los mismos cambios en el css.